# How to install “libspotify12” on Debian Bullseye?

Tags: linux, installation, media-player, spotify, debian-bullseye

I'm running Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye).

I'm trying to install the Tizonia cloud music player for the terminal. I ran the command:

```
curl -kL https://github.com/tizonia/tizonia-openmax-il/raw/master/tools/install.sh | bash
```

But I end up getting the following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package libspotify12
```

This stalls the installation, and also makes it impossible to clean up my mess using this command:

```
sudo apt-get -y remove --purge tizonia-all && sudo apt-get -y autoremove
```

Because Tizonia never ends up getting installed:

```
E: Unable to locate package tizonia-all
```

What source should I add to my Debian APT sources list to get access to `libspotify12`, in order for the installation to proceed normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libspotify` is proprietary code, so it can't be hosted in Debian's repos.
It is to be found in the developer Mopidy's own
[APT repository](https://github.com/mopidy/libspotify-deb/find/master).

The README says this:

> **Install from APT archive**
>
> If you want to install the package, you can do so from the Mopidy APT
> archive at https://apt.mopidy.com/.
>
> 1. Add the archive's GPG key:
>
>    ```
>    wget -q -O - https://apt.mopidy.com/mopidy.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
>    ```
> 2. Add the following to `/etc/apt/sources.list`, or if you have the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, add it to a file called
>    `mopidy.list` in that directory:
>
>    ```
>    sudo wget -q -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mopidy.list https://apt.mopidy.com/stretch.list
>    ```
> 3. Install packages:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get update
>    sudo apt-get install libspotify12 libspotify-dev
>    ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I marked it as accepted, because it works, (up to date) but do consider that `apt-key` is deprecated. (You might want to edit that.) Thanks again.

Comment: This remark should be addressed to the developer Mopidy himself.

Comment: Fair, but it couldn't hurt to include an updated solution at the bottom of your answer, all without modifying the quoted readme. That's up to you. ;) Thanks again for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this myself but try this -

https://github.com/mopidy/libspotify-deb